# Orca and Setup Project: show checkboxes form conditionally

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer, setup-project, orca

I'm creating an installer for my application, using `Setup Project` in `VS 10`. The installer has a `Checkboxes (A)` form in it. My problem is, I want to show that form conditionally, based on one registry entry. How can I achieve this? I'm using `Orca` to edit my installer file, but what should I change to show this form conditionally? When I edit `InstallUISequence`>`CustomCheckA_SetProperty_CHECKBOX1`, the value of the checkbox is changed. I can't see any other property, I could edit to achieve this :(. Please help, thanks a lot! Greetings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a [registry search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see if your entry exists or not. The search name is actually an installer public property, so you can use it to set a condition.

To hide/show enable/disable controls from an MSI dialog you need to add a control condition, [in Control Condition table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Make sure you define two control conditions for the same control, one to hide it if the condition is not met and one to show it when the condition is true.